# Actualizar Angular 10.1 a 11, problema de dependencias

Tags: angular, ionic, npm, dependencias

Estoy intentado actualizar mi Angular 10 a 11, que actualmente tiene la configuración con "ng version":

```html
Angular CLI: 10.2.3
Node: 12.16.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 10.1.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms     
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------     
@angular-devkit/architect         0.1001.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1001.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1001.7
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.1001.7
@angular-devkit/core              10.1.5
@angular-devkit/schematics        10.2.3
@angular/cli                      10.2.3
@angular/fire                     6.0.3
@angular/google-maps              11.2.10
@angular/service-worker           10.2.5
@schematics/angular               9.1.15
@schematics/update                0.1002.3
rxjs                              6.6.7
typescript                        4.0.8
webpack                           4.46.0
```

Al realizar tanto un "npm audit fix" como cuando intento actualizar angular con "ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11" o un "npm update", obtengo el siguiente problema, que entiendo que tiene que ver con dependencias pero no tengo ni idea de como poder solucionarlo. He intentado limpiar cache reinstalar angular, pero no consigo hacer que se actualice de ninguna manera.

```html
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1001.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.1102.14" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular-devkit/build-angular@">=0.800.0" from @ionic/angular-toolkit@2.3.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ionic/angular-toolkit
npm ERR!     dev @ionic/angular-toolkit@"^2.3.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@11.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^11.0.0 || ^11.2.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1102.14
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^0.1102.14" from the root project
```

Mi package.json ahora mismo es el siguiente:

```html
"dependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1001.3",
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1001.3",
        "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "^0.1001.3",
        "@angular-devkit/build-webpack": "^0.1001.3",
        "@angular-devkit/core": "^10.1.3",
        "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^10.1.3",
        "@angular/animations": "^10.1.3",
        "@angular/cli": "^10.1.3",
        "@angular/common": "^10.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "^10.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.1.3",
        "@angular/core": "^10.1.3",
        "@angular/fire": "^6.0.3",
        "@angular/forms": "^10.1.3",
        "@angular/google-maps": "^11.2.10",
        "@angular/language-service": "^10.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.1.3",
        "@angular/router": "^10.1.3",
        "@angular/service-worker": "^10.1.3",
        "@byteowls/capacitor-filesharer": "^2.0.0",
        "@capacitor/android": "^2.4.6",
        "@capacitor/core": "^2.4.6",
        "@ionic-native/call-number": "^5.28.0",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.28.0",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^5.22.0-beta-1",
        "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^5.28.0",
        "@ionic-native/email-composer": "^5.28.0",
        "@ionic-native/file": "^5.28.0",
        "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^5.28.0",
        "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.28.0",
        "@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio": "^5.28.0",
        "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^5.27.0-beta-20200630",
        "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^5.33.0",
        "@ionic-native/location-accuracy": "^5.28.0",
        "@ionic-native/market": "^5.28.0",
        "@ionic-native/native-geocoder": "^5.28.0",
        "@ionic-native/network": "^5.33.0",
        "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.32.0",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.28.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.28.0",
        "@ionic-native/vibration": "^5.28.0",
        "@ionic/angular": "^5.3.3",
        "@ionic/lab": "^3.2.8",
        "@ionic/storage": "^2.3.1",
        "@mobiscroll/angular": "file:./src/lib/mobiscroll-package/mobiscroll-angular-5.6.3.tgz",
        "@schematics/angular": "^9.0.4",
        "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
        "call-number": "^1.0.1",
        "capacitor-resources": "^2.0.5",
        "cordova": "^10.0.0",
        "cordova-android": "^9.0.0",
        "cordova-androidx-build": "^1.0.4",
        "cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
        "cordova-ios": "6.1.1",
        "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^2.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.8",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "5.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-email-composer": "0.9.2",
        "cordova-plugin-file": "6.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "3.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-file-transfer-ios-fix": "^1.7.2",
        "cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio": "^3.0.1",
        "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "git://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps.git#multiple_maps",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-local-notification": "^0.9.0-beta.2",
        "cordova-plugin-market": "^1.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^3.4.1",
        "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": "^2.3.0",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
        "cordova-plugin-vibration": "^3.1.1",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
        "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^6.0.3",
        "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^5.0.2",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
        "firebase": "^7.21.1",
        "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
        "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.13",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
        "ionic-selectable": "^4.7.1",
        "moment": "^2.29.0",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
        "native-run": "^1.1.0",
        "npx": "^10.2.2",
        "rxjs": "~6.6.3",
        "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5",
        "typescript": "^4.0.2",
        "webpack": "^4.44.2",
        "webpack-subresource-integrity": "^1.4.1",
        "xcode": "^3.0.1",
        "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@capacitor/cli": "^2.4.6",
        "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.3",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.14",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
        "@types/node": "~14.11.2",
        "codelyzer": "~6.0.0",
        "cordova-res": "^0.15.3",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~6.0.0",
        "karma": "^5.2.2",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "protractor": "^7.0.0",
        "sass-loader": "^10.0.2",
        "ts-node": "~9.0.0",
        "tslint": "^6.1.3",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
        "webpack-subresource-integrity": "^1.4.1"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "platforms": [
        "browser",
        "ios",
        "android"
    ],
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
                "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-sqlserver": {},
            "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
            "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": {
                "LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION": "Use geocoder service"
            },
            "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
            "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": {},
            "call-number": {},
            "cordova-plugin-email-composer": {
                "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": {
                "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-file": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-vibration": {},
            "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {},
            "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
            "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {
                "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio": {
                "FACEID_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "Login now...."
            },
            "cordova-plugin-market": {},
            "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {
                "LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION": "Esta app solicita la localización para obtener la posición desde la que registra sus fichajes.",
                "LOCATION_ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app wants to get your location always, even this app runs in background.",
                "LOOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "Esta app solicita la localización para obtener la posición desde la que registra sus fichajes."
            },
            "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": {
                "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "27.+"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": {},
            "cordova-plugin-camera": {
                "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-network-information": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "browser",
            "android",
            "ios"
        ]
```

Comment: Te sugiero siempre seguir la guia de Angular para actualizar la version de tu proyecto, siguiendola al pie de la letra te aseguraras de que las dependencias directas de Angular se mantengan consistentes https://update.angular.io/

Comment: He seguido exactamente esa guía, pero en cuanto realizo el primer paso que es el update de angular cli y angular core me da ese problema

Comment: utiliza el comando `--force`

Comment: Esto tampoco me funciona, me lanza el mismo mensaje